# Save settings per developer in Git

Tags: version-control, ide, settings

Persistence is an essential requirement for preferences. Developer's preferences are saved in `.idea/` folder. It is recommended to add `.idea/` to `.gitignore` to avoid merge conflicts. But then settings are lost whenever

- Project is cloned to a new environment
- Project settings are messed up and you want to roll back
- New developer joins a team

I end up emailing `idea.zip` folder to myself to not lose my settings. This feels wrong because the whole point of Git is to track changes to files. If I can email settings, then I can email the whole project as well.

I can use some dirty hack like a separate git project for developer settings. Import settings branch, merge dev source code branch, resolve conflicts,... But this is even more manual than `.idea.zip` email.

What is the right way to store developer's project settings on Git, but avoid edit warring? Is there a way to tell git to version settings per developer?

Comment: IDE settings could be stored in a different, personal Git repository.

Comment: This pretty much answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11968647/3608792

Comment: @DanWilson the answer suggests to gitignore and lose your settings. Great plan! Can gitignore source code and use emails as a source control as well (sarcasm).

Comment: @Basilevs. Sure, but this is lame workaround. Clean solution would be to have .idea/Alice .idea/Bob etc where Alice and Bob are Github usernames. Making several repos to patch Github design flaw is just bad.

Comment: @Stepan you only lose settings when you blow away your repo or clone a new one. You're making a mountain out of a mole hill IMHO. I use the same repo directory for months or years.

Answer (score 0):

"Oh, those Russians!"

1. "Recommended" != "Must to"
2. If you *want to share* `.idea`, you *have to share it*
3. "Share it" doesn't mean "merge it into code of project"; hint - Git have "branches"
4. Git can use *custom* mergetools

Sapienti sat

Comment: "Git have branches" - welcome to branching hell. I am  not OK to create ten times more branches, but OK to add ten extra branches (one per developer), Also, generic branches imply three way merges, which is a nightmare. "Custom merge tools" - this is exactly my question.